# Java: Files is not compressed properly(with file permission)

Tags: java, zip

I have making zip file using java. hence, i had face a small problem.  Execute files(*.sh and binary files) are compressed is not properly with his file permissions. pls find the following code for make zip

```
    public static void makeZip(String compressDirPath, String zipName, String outputLoc) 
    throws java.io.IOException
    {
        if(outputLoc.equals("") || outputLoc == null)  outputLoc = ".";
        File compressDir = new File(compressDirPath);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputLoc+"/"+zipName));
        compress(compressDir, compressDir, zos);
        zos.close();
      }

  private static void compress(File compressDir, File base, ZipOutputStream zos) throws java.io.IOException
  {
    File[] files = compressDir.listFiles();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[18024];
    int read = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = files.length; i < n; i++) {
      if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
        compress(files[i], base, zos);
      } else {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(files[i].getPath().substring(base.getPath().length() + 1));
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);
        while (-1 != (read = in.read(buffer))) { zos.write(buffer, 0, read); }
        in.close();
      }
    }
  }
```

When i have unzip the zipped file, execute files create by normal file. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I get it, file permissions are not stored within `zip` archives. You can use a `tar` archive instead. See [JTar](http://code.google.com/p/jtar/) or org.apache.tools.tar.

Comment: And gzipping (or otherwise compressing) a tar file yields a higher compression rate.